# AWS CloudFormation - Correct Usage of Default Key Policy in AWS::KMS::Key

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy a KMS CMK with the default Key Policy. Per the documentation, if you don't specify a policy when creating a key, AWS uses the *default key policy*.  However, when using CloudFormation, the Property KeyPolicy is required. Anyone know how to specify the default policy in the KeyPolicy statement or am I missing something?

I am trying to create an `AWS::KMS::Key` resource, per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-key.html) there should be the ability to use the **default key policy** as the `KeyPolicy` property, however, as the documentation states:

> If you are unsure of which policy to use, consider the default key policy. This is the key policy that AWS KMS applies to KMS keys that are created by using the CreateKey API with no specified key policy. It gives the AWS account that owns the key permission to perform all operations on the key. It also allows you write IAM policies to authorize access to the key. For details, see Default key policy in the AWS Key Management Service Developer Guide.

Unfortunately, the `KeyPolicy` resource is marked as having a Required value, while using the default key policy explicitly calls for passing no value. **How can I use the default key policy in the KeyPolicy Property when it requires a value to be passed?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more research on this, it appears the correct way to handle this is to pass the equivalent of the what the default key policy imposes into the actual CloudFormation property.

Consider the following [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-default.html) on default key policy:

> The following default key policy statement is critical.
>
> It gives the AWS account that owns the KMS key full access to the KMS
> key.
>
> Unlike other AWS resource policies, a AWS KMS key policy does not
> automatically give permission to the account or any of its users. To
> give permission to account administrators, the key policy must include
> an explicit statement that provides this permission, like this one.
>
> It allows the account to use IAM policies to allow access to the KMS
> key, in addition to the key policy.
>
> Without this permission, IAM policies that allow access to the key are
> ineffective, although IAM policies that deny access to the key are
> still effective.
>
> It reduces the risk of the key becoming unmanageable by giving access
> control permission to the account administrators, including the
> account root user, which cannot be deleted.
>
> The following key policy statement is the entire default key policy
> for KMS keys created programmatically. It's the first policy statement
> in the default key policy for KMS keys created in the AWS KMS console.

The last line, in particular, reveals the answer:

**The following key policy statement is the entire default key policy for KMS keys created programmatically. It's the first policy statement in the default key policy for KMS keys created in the AWS KMS console.**

```
{
  "Sid": "Enable IAM policies",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"
   },
  "Action": "kms:*",
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

Therefore, because the `KeyPolicy` field in a CloudFormation `AWS::KMS::Key` is required, to pass in the Default Key Policy, you need to submit the above code block that would normally be created for you (if you called the KMS API without  an explicit KeyPolicy).

Comment: As an additional, I've submitted for clarification in the AWS docs as well.